# Mysql query show no result with some bad words?

Tags: mysql

I am working on an adult site, for this site I have created an internal research.

For search I use this query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
id_photo, title, description, model, data_ins, 
MATCH(title, description, model) AGAINST('".trim(strtolower(addslashes($_GET['q'])))."') as score 
FROM ".$prefix."photo 
WHERE MATCH(title, description, model) AGAINST('".trim(strtolower(addslashes($_GET['q'])))."') 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$step."
```

Everything works smoothly and without php or mysql errors, but the client pointed out a strange thing to me.

eg :

- searching for the word starting with "c" and ending with "ck" the
  query returns no results.
- searching for the word starting with "d"
  and ending with "ck" the query returns the correct results.

I use something similar to this to verify if there are results:

```
$photo_query_id = $db->prepare("my query");
        $photo_query_id->execute();
         if($photo_query_id->rowCount() < 1){
         //...
         }
```

The two words are both used hundreds of times in both titles and descriptions, so why does mysql sometimes prefer not to show results?

Is there a list of bad words in some mysql config file that is blocking queries? And in case where do I find it and how do I modify it?

Comment: Please learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Maybe you've configured a stopwords list. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-innodb-search-indexes

Comment: 1. still a work in progress. 2. sorry, but i can't show adult sites url here. 3. I have seen those lists but from what I understand they are used by mysql to understand what you are looking for, and in any case there is no the word with the "c" in the lists.

Comment: I understand why you're not showing sample data here. But if you can't provide some way for us to reproduce the problem, I don't see how we can help you. Is there something about my db-fiddle that's not representative of what you're doing?

Comment: Here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7h3rfGQAnynACYBpW3BfK4/0

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kn2rZ1zrczqKiLb9x3y2U9/1 I made some changes, complicated the query, but it always seems to work, but in my site it keeps showing zero results ... what else can it be? ubuntu 20.04? php8.1?

Comment: It's possible that the word is used too much, so the FT index has determined that it's not discriminatory enough.

Comment: maybe something in the way I check for results? (I have updated the text)

Comment: sorry what's the FT?

Comment: FT is short for Full-Text

Comment: It's possible? It's surely used a lot of time... but, come on... this word in an adult site can't show no result...

Comment: Do you really want a search that returns 90% of the videos?

Comment: I'm afraid so, I can't decide ... anyway they are limited by start and step ....

Comment: In this sector they don't have much imagination, the words used are always the same, like this there will be many other words used thousands of times, and they are probably the most important, I can't tell them: I'm sorry but the server with these words does not show results because you use them too much ...

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BOOLEAN MODE` search or use the InnoDB database engine for your table. When you do a natural language search against a MyISAM full-text index, words that appear in more than 50% of the rows are treated as stopwords.

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> The 50% threshold can surprise you when you first try full-text searching to see how it works, and makes InnoDB tables more suited to experimentation with full-text searches. If you create a MyISAM table and insert only one or two rows of text into it, every word in the text occurs in at least 50% of the rows. As a result, no search returns any results until the table contains more rows. Users who need to bypass the 50% limitation can build search indexes on InnoDB tables, or use the boolean search mode explained in Section [12.10.2, “Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html)”][2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I'm going to study and try to understand well the differences between natural search and boolean mode, and then I'll try to figure out what to do ...